# How do I detect a Pop-up? How do I click on the clickable option boxes in the Popup?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

The production website I'm interfacing with, occasionally triggers a POP-up. It always happens in the same place in the code.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: 
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"css selector","selector":"li:nth-child(4) > div"}
```

I have been unsuccessful in:

1. detecting the pop-up when it appears and
2. being able to click on the responses in the pop-up, ususally I want to click on 'Continue"

Does anyone have experience with this problem and how did you input code that worked?

My code

```py
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "{}".format(targetTeeTime)).click()
print("Holding one Tee Time", end=' ')
print_now()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li:nth-child(4) > div").click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ftMs-guestTbd .ftMs-listItem > span").click()
```

Console print out

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
  File "NewAutoReservations2.0.py", line 1054, in alarm
  File "NewAutoReservations2.0.py", line 360, in matchDayAndData
  File "NewAutoReservations2.0.py", line 1054, in alarm
  File "NewAutoReservations2.0.py", line 264, in matchDayAndData
  File "NewAutoReservations2.0.py", line 117, in numTeeTimesDecision
  File "NewAutoReservations2.0.py", line 752, in makeOneReservation
  File "selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 857, in find_element
  File "selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 435, in execute
  File "selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate 
element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"li:nth-child(4) > div"}
  (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.129)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00A18893+48451]
        (No symbol) [0x009AB8A1]
        (No symbol) [0x008B5058]
        (No symbol) [0x008E0467]
        (No symbol) [0x008E069B]
        (No symbol) [0x0090DD92]
        (No symbol) [0x008FA304]
        (No symbol) [0x0090C482]
        (No symbol) [0x008FA0B6]
        (No symbol) [0x008D7E08]
        (No symbol) [0x008D8F2D]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00C78E3A+2540266]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00CB8959+2801161]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00CB295C+2776588]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00AA2280+612144]
        (No symbol) [0x009B4F6C]
        (No symbol) [0x009B11D8]
        (No symbol) [0x009B12BB]
        (No symbol) [0x009A4857]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76590099+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77767B6E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77767B3E+238]
```

[image: The Popup]

Comment: Please always provide a minimum reproducible work/code snippets in order to reproduce the error and thus provide you some way around to solve it.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example